# My computer is booting to a full purple screen and asking for a username and password

Tags: boot, grub2, password

Yesterday I reboot my computer to find out something went wrong the computer does not boot after about 10-15 sec after I press the power button it goes to a full purple screen I can't do anything to the grub and I can't boot I am positive it not a bios or uefi password.

Answer (score 2):

If your grub2 version is prior to 2.02, you can bypass Grub2 password protection by **hitting backspace 28 times** at the username prompt.

More details here: http://hmarco.org/bugs/CVE-2015-8370-Grub2-authentication-bypass.html

Once booted, you will be able to modify your grub configuration (and also update its version)

Comment: You don't need username, just hit the backspace key 28 times when the grub ask you to type your username...

Comment: After a reboot yesterday, it's likely that Grub was updated to fix that bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Grub2 password prompt. You need to enter the Grub username and password that you have previously defined.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

Picking parts of this [page about Grub2 passwords](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords), we get this:

> GRUB 2 offers basic password protection for its menu and terminal.
>   This page will detail the procedures necessary to establish and use
>   the GRUB 2 password option.
>
> ```
> Enter username:
> stnicholas
> Enter password:
> _
> ```
>
> If GRUB 2 is set up to boot directly to a password-protected menuentry
>   without displaying a menu, the username/password prompt will appear
>   and booting will not occur until they are correctly entered.
>
> Errors in creating a password-protected GRUB 2 menu may result in an
>   unbootable system. To restore a system with broken passwords, access
>   and edit the GRUB 2 configuration files using the LiveCD or another
>   OS.
>
> If GRUB 2 is set up to boot automatically to a password-protected
>   menuentry the user has no option to back out of the password prompt to
>   select another menuentry. Holding the SHIFT key will not display the
>   menu in this case. The user must enter the correct username and
>   password. If unable, the configuration files will have to be edited
>   via the LiveCD or other means to fix the problem.

As to why the screen is purple, I assume it's because that's what you've configured. I like purple, but I don't think I'd choose it for a screen background colour.